# Glitch on First Frame of Animation

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, .fbx, external-applications

I'm having a problem with some of my animations. My main character is an ape climbing a building. On frame 1 of the animation, the left leg gets distorted (see image). Not sure why this is happening, I did not design it this way. As an easy fix, in the Timeline, when I click the button "jump to first frame in frame range," it always fixes the problem and the leg returns to the correct position as I designed it. However, when I export the model and armature as FBX and import into Unity, this glitch appears in Unity on the first frame of the animation.

[image]

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you parent the knees pole targets to the toes it doesn't help to bend the right way. If you parent them to the feet controllers it seems to works:

[image]

Comment: From a friend: The glitch in the leg is due to a dependency cycle (like a feedback loop) in the rigging. The IK pole target (knee control) is dependent on the position of the leg/foot/toe through parenting, while at the same time the leg orientation is dependent on the pole target's position through the constraint. So Blender gets confused about what to evaluate first.

It's a known limitation of the code (the Dependency Graph, specifically) that doesn't exist in other 3d apps apparently, and is supposed to be fixed in 2.80.

Comment: I actually had to parent the knee controls to the root bone in edit mode, then make adjustments to them across many animations in pose mode. It did seem to solve the problem. Thanks for the input!

Comment: sure you can parent them to the root bone, that's what I do, but it is also possible to parent it to the controller for example, I thought you wanted it to follow the movement of the foot